# actionlib tutorial errors

Tags: ros, boost, actionlib, actionlib-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm new to ROS and I've been having some trouble getting started with the actionlib tutorial under Fuerte and Xubuntu 12.04.

I'm following the steps to create a [Simple Action Server](http://ros.org/wiki/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29). In step 1.1, I used the following command to define the Fibonacci action, and then used the following command to generate the message files:

```
$ rosrun actionlib_msgs genaction.py . Fibonacci.action
```

This didn't work at first, and I needed to follow the guidance in [another ROS answers topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/35685/actionlib-error/) to continue. The code that worked was as follows:

```
$ rosrun actionlib_msgs genaction.py -o msg/ action/Fibonacci.action
```

I followed the steps to edit CMakeLists.txt, created fibonacci_server.cpp, and copied the code given by the tutorial. If I make the project (with rosmake), though, the build fails with the follow error.

```
  Scanning dependencies of target fibonacci_server
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/will/ros_workspace/tutorials/learning_actionlib/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/will/ros_workspace/tutorials/learning_actionlib/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fibonacci_server.dir/src/fibonacci_server.o
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/fibonacci_server
  /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/fibonacci_server.dir/src/fibonacci_server.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
  /usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
  /usr/lib64/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/fibonacci_server] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/will/ros_workspace/tutorials/learning_actionlib/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fibonacci_server.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/will/ros_workspace/tutorials/learning_actionlib/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/will/ros_workspace/tutorials/learning_actionlib/build'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36470/actionlib-tutorial-errors/) by [willshepherdson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2423/willshepherdson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need this in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_add_executable(fibonacci_server src/fibonacci_server.cpp)
rosbuild_link_boost(fibonacci_server thread)
```

This [changed in Fuerte](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration#Errors_linking_boost_.28e.g._with_Boost_signals_or_thread.29). The tutorial explains it correctly, but you need to click on the `fuerte` button at the top of the page to see the new `CMakeLists.txt` update.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-17**:
If this answer is correct, please mark it so we know to update that Tutorial.

**Comment by [willshepherdson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2423/willshepherdson/) on 2012-06-18**:
Works like a charm; thank you very much!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-18**:
That Tutorial is already correct *if* you select Fuerte up at the top of the page. Unfortunately, the default version is Electric.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-06-20**:
Jack, I actually added the distro switch and the doc update after you answered the question. (:

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-20**:
Ah, good job. Thanks! There is an open defect ticket to change the `Version()` default to Fuerte.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-06-20**:
Where is that ticket? (Never mind, found it: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3967 )